# How KVM is allocating memory to VM without generating enough page-faults?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, dynamic-memory-allocation, kvm

I'm trying to understand the KVM memory allocator for x86. I'm doing this experiment - Allocating 16GB of memory using mmap (and touching it) on freshly booted VM, so that host system memory usage increase by 16 GB (host start allocating that memory to qemu as the guest started touching mmaped region). While allocating memory on VM, I'm also counting the page-faults generated by qemu-system process during the allocation using perf stat.
I observe the number of page-faults generated by qemu process is very low (in range of 0-300), I was expecting that it would generate 4,194,304 page-faults. (16GB/4KB, note-I have completely disable hugepages).
What am I missing here??

Comment: I haven't personally used `kvm` but I imagine a lot pre-fetching happens specifically to minimize page faults.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have touched all pages?

> The Linux kernel uses lazy (on-demand) allocation of physical pages, deferring the allocation until necessary and avoiding allocating physical pages which will never actually be used. Memory mappings generally start out with no physical pages attached.

2. You may have huge page support enabled

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
```

Comment: Yes, you're right.
1. I touch each 4KB page individually by writing a byte to it.

2. Hugepages is one the reason behind low page-faults. It contains the code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67034697/13286624

3. I haven't check this part in linux-kvm code but it may be possible that there are pre-allocations happening to minimize the page-faults generated.